# How can I get a list of all packages in a repository section from command line?

Tags: command-line, package-management, synaptic

In Synaptic, one can list packages by section. For example, in the image below all packages of the "Amateur Radio (universe)" section are listed.

How can I get such a list (edit: with package description) at the command line?

I need a raw list; a terminal application like `aptitude` will not do.

[image: synaptic]

Comment: @bodhi.zazen that is a good suggestion, but does not search the Section only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, though you say you don't want to use aptitude because of the output, you need to know that you can modify it to get what you like:

```
aptitude -F'|%p|%d|' search '?section(hamradio)'
```

The trick is in the `-F` switch that modifies the output format. `%p` means package. This also outputs when package has various architectures (ie amd64 vs i386), and `%d` which outputs the description. You can personalize the search pattern even more to for example not installed packages:

```
aptitude -F'|%p|%d|' search '?section(hamradio) !~i'
```

where `~i` means installed and the `!` is a not, so it reads as "not (!) installed (~i)", or if you only want the ones that are available to your architecture:

```
aptitude -F'|%p|%d|' search '?section(hamradio) ~r native'
```

`~r` being `?architecture()` which matches the architecture of the package and `native` which lists only the ones that have the same architecture as the system, the equivalent to `dpkg --print-architecture`.

The previous line can therefore be written even more concisely as:

```
aptitude -F'|%p|%d|' search '~s hamradio ~r native'
```

Comment: Very elegant, especially with `-F'|%p|%d|'`. However, would it be possible not to list the `:i386` packages by adding a `!`-expression to the `search` string?

Comment: @GinGordon yeah, just add `~r native` to the search terms. `~r` being `?architecture` which match the architecture of the package and `native` which list only the ones that has the same architecture than the system, the equivalent to `dpkg --print-architecture`. BTW, you wanted the list with package description?

Comment: Great! And yes, I have edited the question to include package description. Please, edit your answer accordingly and you deservingly will receive my best answer vote for being the most concise.

Comment: @GinGordon check it out.

Comment: ...to discover one `i386` package called `morse` that has not been ported to `amd64`. By consequence, my solution has a `|wc -l` of 74 lines, yours only 73!

Comment: @GinGordon weird... debian has both i386 and amd64 packages. http://paste.ubuntu.com/7538389/. Maybe writing an angry mail to the maintainers would fix stuff.

Comment: `aptitude -F'|%p|%d|' search '~s hamradio ~r native'` is even more bad-ass concise. Thanks for voting comment.

Comment: @GinGordon if you install the `aptitude-doc` package and navigate to `/usr/share/doc/aptitude/html/en/index.html` with your browser you will find in `file:///usr/share/doc/aptitude/html/en/ch02s04s05.html` all the nasty perks.

Comment: Check [this](http://hamwaves.com/linux.ham.packages/en/index.html#package-list) out.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure the [dctrl-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dctrl-tools)[image: Install dctrl-tools] package is installed. It provides useful commands for searching the apt and dpkg package lists. To get a full description of all packages from a particular section that are installable with apt, run

```
grep-aptavail -F Section hamradio
```

This will show the full package metadata for every package in the `hamradio` section. If all you want to see are the package names, run

```
grep-aptavail -n -F Section -s Package hamradio
```

If your system is set up for multiarch, the same package may show up more than once in this listing if it is built for more than one architecture. So to refine this further, use either

```
grep-aptavail -n -F Section -s Package hamradio | sort | uniq
```

or

```
grep-aptavail -n -F Section -s Package hamradio | sort -u
```

to sort the package list and remove duplicate packages with the same name.

Note that you will have to use the actual name of the section, which is different from the "human-readable" name that Synaptic shows in its GUI. For example, the searches above use the section name `hamradio` instead of the string "Amateur Radio" shown in Synaptic.

See the man page for [grep-aptavail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep-aptavail.1.html) for a full description of all options and some examples.

Answer (score 3):

#### More fields on a single line, with arbitrary separator

The following one-liner will print all unique package names of a repository section, **together with their description, each on a single line.** All fields are separated by a pipe character, i.e. ready for conversion into a [Markdown pipe table](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#pipe-tables). The [resulting table](http://hamwaves.com/linux.ham.packages/en/index.html) can be found on my web site.

```
grep-aptavail -n -s Package,Description -F Section hamradio |paste -sd '||\n' |sed 's:^:|:' |sort -u
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command to get a list of packages belonging to a given Section:

```
$ dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package} ${Section}\n' | awk '{if ($2 == "shells") {print $1}}'
bash
bash-completion
busybox-initramfs
busybox-static
dash
zsh
zsh-common
```