# How to get a list of the package home pages in a repository section from command line?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

A while ago, I asked here about [how to get the list of packages in a repository section from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/q/469612/164341).

According to the Synaptic Package Manager, many of these packages feature a home page. How can I add this to my automatically generated package list from the command line?

[image: Synaptic Package Manager showing link to package home page]

It does not seem to be as simple as adding an argument option to any of the previous answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend [Braim's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/473511/449) to just pull back package names, then get the full package info for each, and `awk` that down for format.

```
aptitude -F'%p' search '?section(hamradio) ?architecture(amd64)' \
| xargs apt-cache show \
| awk '/^Package/ {printf("\n"$2)} /^Homepage/ {printf (": "$2)}'
```

I'm adding an additional architecture limit to the query to stop (in my case) duplicates in i386 architecture coming through. You could omit that if you wanted.

```
acfax
aldo
antennavis: http://www.include.gr/antennavis.html
aprsd: http://sourceforge.net/projects/aprsd/
aprsdigi: http://aprsdigi.sourceforge.net/
```

The first two don't have homepages specified. The last three do.

If you only want the ones with homepages, I suggest switching up the `awk` to only print when it finds a homepage. We'll store the package name in a variable. Like so:

```
... | awk '/^Package/ {p=$2} /^Homepage/ {printf ("%s: %s\n", p, $2)}'
```

Comment: Very nice piping from `aptitude` to `apt-cache show` and finally to `awk` of course.

Comment: No wonder you've got 126K rep and 26 gold badges! ;-)

Comment: This answer gave me a great head start to [pull a few more tricks](http://askubuntu.com/a/620285/164341) with `$1="";sub(FS,"");` and `awk` conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up [Oli's great answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/606748/164341) and made it [conditional](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-13). The `$1="";sub(FS,"");` code hack does away with the first `Description-en:` field and the single space field separator, all in a very concise way. It is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22908787/2192488).

```
aptitude -F'%p' search '~r native ~s hamradio' \
    |xargs apt-cache show \
    |awk '/^Package/{name=$2} \
          /^Description-en/{$1="";sub(FS,"");description=$0}
          /^Description-en/{description=$0} \
          /^Homepage/{url=$2} \
          /^$/{if(url) {printf("|["name"]("url")|"description"|\n"); url=""} \
               else {printf("|"name"|"description"|\n")}}'
```

It now yields complete [Pandoc Markdown table](http://pandoc.org/README.html#tables) rows, which eventually get converted to a [HTML table on my website](http://hamwaves.com/linux.ham.packages/en/index.html).

```
|acfax|Receive faxes using your radio and sound card|
|aldo|Morse code training program|
|[antennavis](http://www.include.gr/antennavis.html)|antenna radiation pattern visualization software|
|[aprsd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aprsd/)|Internet Gateway for the Automatic Position Reporting System|
|[aprsdigi](http://aprsdigi.sourceforge.net/)|digipeater for APRS|
|[ax25-apps](http://aprsdigi.sourceforge.net/)|AX.25 ham radio applications|
|[ax25-node](http://aprsdigi.sourceforge.net/)|Amateur Packet Radio Node program|
|[ax25-tools](http://aprsdigi.sourceforge.net/)|tools for AX.25 interface configuration|
|[ax25-xtools](http://aprsdigi.sourceforge.net/)|tools for AX.25 interface configuration -- X11-based|
|[ax25mail-utils](http://aprsdigi.sourceforge.net/)|hamradio utilities for fbb|
```